# CakePHP 3 - View class "CsvView.csv" is missing issue

Tags: csv, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to include a csv exporter in my application, And i used https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/cakephp-csvview.

It works fine on my local machine but for some reason it doesn't work on my server. It throws me **View class "CsvView.csv" is missing.** error. Is there a way to fix this issue?

Here's my controller for reference

```
public function export() {
    $this->response->download('export.csv');

    // $opts1['order'] = array('Blogs.created' => 'desc');
    // $blogsinfos = $this->Blogs->find('all',$opts1);


    $opts1['order'] = array('Incomes.title' => 'desc');
    $data = $this->Incomes->find('all',$opts1)->toArray();


    $_serialize = 'data';
    // Give the needed the colums to extract 
    $_extract = ['id', 'title' ,'description' , 'created' , 'amount'];

    //headings for the CSV
    $_header = ['ID', 'Title' ,'Description' , 'Created' , 'Amount'];
    $this->set(compact('data', '_serialize', '_header', '_extract'));


    $this->viewBuilder()->className('CsvView.csv');
    return;
}
```

Code to create the downloadable link.

```
<?= $this->Html->link('Monthly Report', [
        'controller' => 'incomes', 
        'action' => 'export',
        '_ext' => 'csv'
        ],

        ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) 
      ?>
```

I'm using CakePHP 3.4.7.

Comment: Did you forget the documented routes part? `// In your routes.php file:
Router::extensions('csv');`

Comment: No not really i have added that.

Comment: Case sensitivity. It should be `CsvView.Csv`, with a capital `C`, not `CsvView.csv`.

Comment: Made it "CsvView.Csv", still the issue occurs. @ndm

Comment: The CsvView plugin is present on the server, and the autoload files have been regenerated since you added it?

Comment: Yes they have. I tried installing a fresh copy but the issue still there. @GregSchmidt